# Find Child elements in a div and append them to another Child element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want the elements to be appended to another elements - they have to
be found in a div class that have `id="parent"`.
the code must be only in clean javascript. The problem is, why i cant use just append - children append only for 1 element(first block) so need a loop that will get every element(2) to append to the (1) element.

```
<!-- FirstBlock -->
<div id="parent">

    <div id="firstElement">
    </div>
    <div id="secondElement">
    </div>

</div>
```

I want it to look like this

```
<!-- FirstBlock -->
<div id="parent">
    <div id="firstElement">
        <div id="secondElement">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code i tried:
        function getElement() {
            var firstElement = document.getElementById('firstElement');
            var secondElement = document.getElementById('secondElement');
            var parent = document.getgetElementById('parent').children;

```
         for(var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++){
            for(firstElement in parent[i]){
                if(!(secondElement in firstElement){
                    firstElement.appendChild(secondElement);
                });
            };
         };
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Vladnaiden/gLdwrqff/1/)

Comment: Are there more elements than `firstElement` and `secondElement`?

Comment: Also, you can't have more than one element with the same `id`, like in your jsfiddle...

Comment: There r only 2 div elements, if u like so u can change it to classes, i just need to know the idea how to do this...

Comment: So if there are only 2, why can't you just do `document.getElementById('firstElement').appendChild(document.getElementById('secondElement');`

Comment: Where's the javascript you tried?  Oh it's in the fiddle.  Might wanna put it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `ID's` being the same, you need to use a `class` attribute instead or change the `ID` for each of those elements. Here's an example of how you could achieve your result(CSS for visual example).

```js
function getElement() {
 var parents = document.getElementsByClassName('parent'),
        parentsLength = parents.length;

 while (parentsLength--){
  var firstElements = parents[parentsLength].getElementsByClassName('firstElement'),
            firstElementsLength = firstElements.length,
   secondElements = parents[parentsLength].getElementsByClassName('secondElement');
        
        while(firstElementsLength--) {
            var secondElementsLength = secondElements.length;
            while(secondElementsLength--) {
 firstElements[firstElementsLength].appendChild(secondElements[secondElementsLength]);
            }
        }
 };
}

getElement();
```

```css
.firstElement {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.secondElement {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<!-- FirstBlock -->
<div class="parent">
    
    <div class="firstElement">
        dddd
    </div>
    <div class="secondElement">
        aaa
    </div>
  
</div>
<!-- SecondBlock -->
<div class="parent">
    
    <div class="firstElement">
        firstElement
    </div>
    <div class="secondElement">
        secondElement
    </div>
    
</div>
<!-- ThirdBlock -->     
<div class="parent">
    
    <div class="firstElement">
        firstElement
    </div>
    <div class="secondElement">
        secondElement
    </div>
    
</div>
    
    I want it look like this
<!-- FirstBlock -->
<div class="parent">
    <div class="firstElement">
        firstElement
        <div class="secondElement">
            secondElement
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- SecondBlock -->
<div class="parent">
    <div class="firstElement">
        firstElement
        <div class="secondElement">
            secondElement
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ThirdBlock -->     
<div>
    <div class="parent">
    <div class="firstElement">
        firstElement
        <div class="secondElement">
            secondElement
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A quick rundown of the JavaScript..
We're getting each element with the `parent` class and setting a variable to the length of that object.
The `while` loop is running through each of those divs and getting the divs inside that contain the `firstElement` and `secondElement` classes.
Then more loops take each element with the class `secondElement` and insert them into the elements with the class `firstElement`.

At the end of it, for every parent div, any divs with a class of `secondElement` will be inserted into **every** div with a class of `firstElement` inside of that parent div.

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLdwrqff/14/) that I went off of for modifications. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML code to have classes, instead of id's. There can't be more than one element with the same id.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="firstElement">
    </div>
    <div class="secondElement">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use the following JavaScript:

```
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
for(i = 0; i < parents.length; i++){
    var current = parents[i];
    var firstElement = current.getElementsByClassName("firstElement")[0];
    var secondElement = current.getElementsByClassName("secondElement")[0];

    firstElement.appendChild(secondElement);
    current.removeChild(firstElement);
}
```